# Banging by Zeresh in the Megillah

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, megillat-esther, haman

In *[The Monsey Mevaser](https://view.flipdocs.com/?ID=10009972_915325)* (page 100), a six-year-old child child asked the following:

We have the custom to bang when we hear Haman's name in the Megillah. Why don’t bang the two times his evil wife Zeresh is mentioned in the Megillah?

Comment: Interesting question - why would you assume that Zeresh is equivalent to Haman? Is she also a descendent of Amalek? Did she almost cause the destruction of the Jewish People?

Comment: @רבות because we say ארור המן ארורה זרש

Comment: The opposite https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56118/759

Comment: There are some people who bang for Zeresh. I do it quietly. :)

Comment: @DoubleAA we also say ארורים כל הרשעים - do we bang for every Rasha? I explained why I thought they were different in my comment above.

Comment: I can’t remember the source but according to the Maharal of Prague antisemites are actually descendants of Amalek, that’s the siman. Although I don’t understand it because the Halacha is Eisav sone leYaakov and not all of Eisav is Amalek

Answer (score 1):

In the link below to a maamar & halachic mechkar מאת הרב יעקב חביב דיין ומו"צ בירושלים, חבר בד"ץ איחוד הרבנים וחבר מכון הלכה חב"ד to the minhag of banging by Kryias Megillah you’ll find reasons for the different minhagim of when to bang and why we limit the places we do so.

https://chabad.info/beis-medrash/461779/

(These are 2 mekoros amongst others mentioned there where it says explicitly to actually bang by Zeresh & their children)
ובאמת כבר הזכיר זאת הגאון רבי אליהו הכהן מאיזמיר בספר מדרש אליהו (מגילת אסתר דף נח עמ' ד) וז"ל: קיבלתי דכשאומרים "ארור המן" או כשמזכירים שמו ושם אשתו וכל בניו מכין, ועושה הקב"ה שירגישו את ההכאות כדי שיקבלו צער גדול, יען שכל הבאים לעולם כאילו בימיהם נעשה הנס, לפי שאם נתקיימה עצתו, לא היו באים לעולם. לכן כל הבאים לעולם צריכים לצערו, ולכן עושה הקב"ה שירגישו ההכאות שמכים בהזכרת שמם עכ"ל.

‎וכן מובא בספר תניא רבתי (סי' מ עמ' מב) דשם כשמביא הוא את המנהג אינו כותב כמו שכתב הרמ"א דנהגו התינוקות וכו' ומזה נשתרבב המנהג וכו' דהשתלשלות המנהג הוא ממנהגי תינוקות. אלא כותב ישר וז"ל: ומכין ברגליהם אבן על אבן ומשברין קדירות כשמעם שבר המן וזרש עכ"ל.

Comment: Thanks for these! Perhaps consider summarising the points raised so that everyone can benefit from the link and the mekoros.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is because in the end when she saw him after the parade, minus their daughter with waste on head she told him to back off and leave the Jews and Mordechai alone because he lost this fight.

That is also a reason why she stayed alive.